# Unable to change property on class through UINavigationcontroller.viewControllers

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I'm using this method to try and get to the property of `UIScrollView` in one of my classes:

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
UINavigationController *nav = delegate.frontViewController.navigationController;
for (UIViewController *controller in nav.viewControllers) {
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[SGInitialViewController class]]) {
        SGInitialViewController *sgInitialController = (SGInitialViewController *)controller;
        SGPlotViewController *plotVC = [sgInitialController.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
        [plotVC.scrollViewMain setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    }
```

The class `SGInitialViewController` is currently *loaded* and its `childViewController` `SGPlotViewController` is *loaded* and is *on screen* as well.
I am unable to change the property of it, no matter how hard I try.
Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think there are better ways to do this, as I said in my answer, but if you want to debug this, start by logging your way backwards. Log plotVC first, and if that doesn't return what you want, log sgInitialController, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to see where the problem is without knowing more about the overall structure of your app. However, digging down through all those controllers to get to a property is just not good design. If it's possible to use a delegate, you should do that -- sometimes, though, depending on how all these controllers are set up, it's hard to get the right reference so a class can set itself as the delegate. In those cases, it's probably best to use a notification. Which ever class contains the code you have in your question should post a notification, and the SGPlotViewController should be registered to receive that notification.